# Exporting exams from R/exams to the d2l learning platform?

Tags: r, r-exams

My university uses the D2L platform so I'm wondering if anyone has had any success exporting exams written by R/exams to that platform. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:* Try to generate exams in Blackboard format using the `exams2blackboard()` function. The output can be imported into the D2L system. See http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/exams2blackboard/ for a first overview.

*More details:*

- The route via Blackboard should work fine for numeric, single-choice and multiple-choice questions. I'm not sure whether cloze exercises would be supported as well in D2L - in any case, they are not supported in Blackboard and hence not in `exams2blackboard()`.
- D2L supports various other import formats and we tried out a few other routes. See the discussion at: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33404&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337
- Apparently, D2L internally uses a QTI 2.1 flavor but with certain extensions. Hence we did not succeed so far to import the output from `exams2qti21()` into D2L.
- For simple single/multiple choice questions a CSV-based exchange format can also be used. I have played around with writing an `exams2d2l()` function. This is available in the discussion linked above.